# Is it possible to convert Database First EF solution to a CodeFirst EF solution

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to convert Database First EF solution to a CodeFirst EF solution. My Database First EF is v6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that by following those few steps: (if you already have C# classes for your entities you can skip step 1)

1. You can use one of these 2 tools to convert your database tables into C# classes:

   i. [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

   ii. [Entity Framework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838)
2. The previous step will generate the DbContext with no initializer (initializer set to null), you need to change that to one of the existing [DbContenxt Initializers](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx) of create your custom one to seed your database.
3. After you the previous steps, you should be able to generate a new database as you normally do with the Code first.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look more into the initializers. I don't recall having to do this with Database First. I think that the Reverse POCO tool  will overwrite all the classes each time it's run. Not optimal if I make many changes and then want to update the schema from the database